# How can I write a query to connect mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express

I have installed mongodb in different server. I have modified my old code

```
db: 'mongodb://localhost/dev',
```

to new code

my username : proUseAdd
password : mongodb@23
ip : 169.213.64.127

I modified like this

```
db: 'mongodb://proUseAdd:mongodb@23@169.213.64.127:27017/dav',
```

I am getting this error

> Could not connect to MongoDB!
>
> Error: failed to connect to
>   [23@169.213.64.127:27017]

---

### UPDATE

i have tried changed my password:mongodb23
query strin:

```
db: 'mongodb://proUseAdd:mongodb23@169.213.64.127:27017/dav',
```

still i'm getting error

> Could not connect to MongoDB!
>
> Error: failed to connect to
>   [169.213.64.127:27017]

Comment: yes why my ip only

Comment: Sorry, you are right; I didn't read carefully and assumed this would be a public IP.

Answer (score 3):

Change your password to something which doesn't contain `@`.

While parsing your connection string, MongoDB driver looks for the `@` character to separate your credentials and the host name. Since your password has an `@` in it, it recognizes your credentials as `proUseAdd:mongodb` and your host name as `23@169.213.64.127:27017`.

Comment: i have folled this one mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]].pls tell mw my query is right?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, added more information about your case. Welcome to the StackOverflow.

Comment: i have changed like this but same error coming .       db: 'mongodb://proUseAdd:mongodb23@169.213.64.127:27017/dav',

Comment: Please update your question with the full error message with the new connection string. Also make sure you've actually changed the password in mongo.

Comment: This is a totally different issue now, make sure your MongoDB is up and running and your app server is able to connect to it. Possibly a firewall issue.

Comment: if i ping server is running